old russian (?) animation with little girl and bunny
I'm looking for an animation probably from the 80's about a lonely little girl who finds a bunny in her yard and keeps it to play with, until it runs away. I used to watch it on a greek VHS which incuded two more animations, one of which I found and is called "travels of an ant" made by Eduard Nazarov in 1983. 

I think this is it. English name is given as "Living Toy", a 1982 short Russian animation. I can't find the original Russian name, but it looks like it was made by the company Союзмультфильм.



I can't watch videos right now, but the description sounds right:

The little girl found in the garden bunny who escaped from Mother hare and took it for a living doll. Called "daughter Kate ," shook in diapers, tied by a bow on each ear , was fed porridge and sweets. Bunny does not eat candy, and all the time wanted to get out of the cradle and run. The girl thought he was sick and went to get drugs. But here zaychiha to know where her baby, seize the moment and with the help of his two children, took him back to the field .


